# Git: How to overwrite timeline on other repo?

Tags: git, github

I recently tried to send a PR on github, but I soon noticed my PR included older commits: [image]

The issue here is that I only made the last commit, as the first one mentioned was merged in another PR and the second one was me updating my own branch.

I asked around how I could prevent it, and most people told me to use `git rebase alexflipnote/master`. Fair enough, I tried it, and it did it pretty well.

However, when I tried to push that to my fork, it said it was unable to push as the commit history was conflicting.

Simplified issue:

```
Now:
A-B-C - - - G
     \     /
      D-E-F

What it should become:
A-B-C-G
      |
      G
```

Whatever I try, I can't seem to make github display `This branch is even with AlexFlipnote:master`. Even after my PR gets merged, it says `This branch is 3 commits ahead, 1 commit behind AlexFlipnote:master` somehow. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply push to GitHub after a rebase because the `remote` history and `local` history have  now diverged.

What you need to do is simply `pull` upstream changes with `--rebase` switch:

```
git pull --rebase upstream master
```

Now if you check your branch, you'll see its all well and good.

```
git status
```

Then push to GitHub with a `--force` switch

```
git push origin master --force
```

Comment: I'm getting `fatal: 'upstream' does not appear to be a git repository`
EDIT: Nevermind, a quick google search fixed this. Thanks!